# How to do a Sum(case when) using JPA

Tags: sql, jpa, jpql

I don't have much background in converting between SQL and JPA-like code so I was wondering how I would go about converting the following to JPA syntax? Or if it's even possible? Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT DLR_CD, COUNT(*),
SUM(CASE WHEN CMPLT_DT='0001-01-01' THEN 1 END),
SUM(CASE WHEN CMPLT_DT!='0001-01-01' THEN 1 END),
SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(CMPLT_DT) = YEAR(CURRENT DATE)-1 THEN 1 END),
SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(CMPLT_DT) = YEAR(CURRENT DATE) THEN 1 END),
SUM(CASE WHEN (CMPLT_DT IS NULL OR CMPLT_DT='0001-01-01') THEN A.RPR_LBR_HR ELSE 0 END)
FROM <db2 table 1> A
join <db2 table 2> B
on ANUN_IND='A'
AND B.PIP_PSP_NO=A.PIP_PSP_NO
--OPTIONAL PARAMS GO HERE
GROUP BY DLR_CD
FOR FETCH ONLY WITH UR;
```

Edit: updated with full, barely-modified query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using criteria api it would look something like this:

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<YourPojo> cq = cb.createQuery(YourPojo.class);
    
    Root<Entity1> root = cq.from(Entity1.class);
    Join<Entity1,Entity2> join = root.join(Entity1_.entity2,JoinType.LEFT);
    /* 
     * the join by ID is implicit when using the .join method, the second
     * condition is added as follows (Since you don't indicate the alias, 
     * I assume it is a field from table 2):
     */
    join.on(cb.equal(join.get(Entity2_.anunInd),'A'));
    
    Calendar dayOne = Calendar.getInstance();
    dayOne.set(1, 0, 1);
    
    //Expression for first and second sum case
    Expression<Long> caseDate = cb.<Long>selectCase().when(cb.equal(root.get(Entity1_.cmpltDt),dayOne.getTime()), 1L).otherwise(0L);
    Expression<Long> sumDate = cb.sum(caseDate);
    
    //Expression for third sum case
    Expression<Long> caseDateWithYearM1 = cb.<Long>selectCase().when(
            cb.equal(cb.function("YEAR", Long.class, root.get(Entity1_.cmpltDt)),
                    cb.sum(cb.function("YEAR", Long.class, cb.literal(new Date())),-1))
            , 1L).otherwise(0L);
    Expression<Long> sumDateWithYearM1 = cb.sum(caseDateWithYearM1);
    
    //Expression for fourth sun case
    Expression<Long> caseDateWithYear = cb.<Long>selectCase().when(
            cb.equal(cb.function("YEAR", Long.class, root.get(Entity1_.cmpltDt)),
                    cb.function("YEAR", Long.class, cb.literal(new Date())))
            , 1L).otherwise(0L);
    Expression<Long> sumDateWithYear = cb.sum(caseDateWithYear);

    Expression<Long> caseNew = cb.<Long>selectCase().when(cb.or(
      cb.equal(root.get(Entity1_.cmpltDt),dayOne.getTime()),
      cb.equal(root.get(Entity1_.cmpltDt),dayOne.getTime())),
             root.get(Entity1_.rprLbrHr)).otherwise(0L);

    Expression<Long> sumNew = cb.sum(caseNew);

    
    cq.multiselect(
            root.get(Entity1_.dlrCd),
            cb.count(root.get(Entity1_.dlrCd)),
            sumDate,
            sumDate,
            sumDateWithYearM1,
            sumDateWithYear,
            sumNew
    );
    
    cq.groupBy(root.get(Entity1_.dlrCd));

    List<YourPojo> resultado = entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

Your Pojo has to have a constructor with the same parameters (order and type) as the multiselect method.

The result query:

```
select
    entity1.DLR_CD as col_0_0_,
    count(entity1.DLR_CD) as col_1_0_,
    sum(case when entity1.CMPLT_DT=? then 1 else 0 
        end) as col_2_0_,
    sum(case when entity1.CMPLT_DT=? then 1  else 0 
        end) as col_3_0_,
    sum(case when extract(year from entity1.CMPLT_DT)=extract(year from ?)+-1 then 1 else 0 
        end) as col_4_0_,
    sum(case when extract(year from entity1.CMPLT_DT)=extract(year from ?) then 1 else 0 
        end) as col_5_0_ ,
    sum(case when entity1.CMPLT_DT is null or entity1.CMPLT_DT=? then entity1.RPR_LBR_HR else 0 
        end) as col_6_0_,
from
    entity1
left join
    entity2 on entity1.PIP_PSP_NO = entity2.PIP_PSP_NO and 
    entity2.ANUN_IND='A'
group by
    entity1.DLR_CD
```

Comment: Hey, @JLazar0 would you be available to chat about this a bit?

Comment: Sure, what do you need

Comment: It's a bit on the complicated side from my perspective (at least being new with this). What I gave is a piece of the query, but now that I see that it's possible, I'd like to talk about converting the whole function. It's not much more, but it includes joins and whatnot. Plus, I'll be pulling information from a DB2 database, pushing that data into an object I made for a DataTable, and then sending that object over an ajax call to fill the DataTable. I have most of the (building the object and loading the table) stuff, but I may need help building the whole query.

Comment: Put the rest of the query and we see that it can be done, but in advance I tell you that Union cannot be done.

It would be necessary to find a similar query without it or throw several queries and add the results.

What you add put it at the end with an EDITED tag so the answer I gave can be valid for people who want to see how to do the sum part

Comment: I correct myself, if it could be done, using Named Queries, which breaks a bit with the JPA philosophy, but it could be done.

Comment: I updated it to reflect the full and barely edited query.

Comment: Currently I'm using Spring Boot and trying to stay with JPA a bit so that I can easily move this around rest api's and whatnot but I'm not too concerned with breaking it a bit.

Comment: I have updated the answer incorporating the join and the new sum, maybe some field is taken from another entity but it would be to change the object that refers to the table (root / join) and the metamodel used to extract the parameter. It is because there are no aliases in all fields and not knowing the model.

Comment: Okay, awesome. I guess my last question is where would I go ahead and put this criteria api code and query? In a service or something? Actually I have one more. If I allowed myself to use Named Queries, could this be done another or more simpler way?

Comment: Or actually, after doing a little bit more research, would JPQL statements work for this as well? (I guess I was being too restrictive when I said JPA).

Comment: I usually use three-layer architectures, the control layer that is responsible for exposing the api, the services layer that is responsible for managing transactionality, and the data access layer in which you would have to create the method with this code.

If you could use JPQL, native queries, named queries ...

I chose Criteria for the answer because you didn't specify and I feel more like it, but you have more tools to make the queries.

Comment: Ah, yeah. Not specifying is definitely my fault. But is it possible to change the SQL code I provided into JPQL and the like? Does it have the Joins, and sum( case whens)?

Comment: Read this https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/group

Comment: Sorry to add another question onto here @JLazar0 , but what are the Entity1 and Entity2 in your answer? Are those pojo's representing the tables?

Comment: no, they are the JPA entities that represent the two tables you use in your query.

Comment: Err, poor wording on my end, but yeah that's effectively what I meant. Awesome